# Difference between Color and UIColor in Swift?

Tags: swift

Whats the difference between using

```
let magenta = Color(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 1.0)
```

and

```
let magenta = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 1.0, alpha:1.0)
```

?

Comment: As far as I see there's no class `Color` ?

Comment: `UIColor` is defined in the UIKit framework. `Color` is probably defined in *your* code.

Comment: @MartinR Color is from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html).

Comment: That is *sample code* for a custom struct and has nothing to do with UIColor.

Comment: `Color` is now a type in SwiftUI https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your question has been answered in the comments to your question, but to provide a complete answer:

Class `Color` does not exist as a pre-defined type in Swift's `UIKit`. In the [example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) you linked to, that is just a custom struct that Apple created to demonstrate how to initialize structs; you cannot actually use that struct in your own code without creating it again yourself (which normally you wouldn't want to do).

Instead, you'll want to create colors using `UIColor`, which *does* come pre-defined in Swift's `UIKit`. You can find the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor). The second example you provided **is, in fact, the correct usage** of `UIColor`:

```
let magenta = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 1.0, alpha:1.0)
```

Note that, as of the release of SwiftUI, there actually *does now* exist a class called `Color`, but this would only be used if you are using the SwiftUI framework, which is obviously not what you were asking about back in 2014.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using both UIKit and SwiftUI in the codebase,

```
UIColor => UIKit
Color => SwiftUI
```